# Creating rectangles on centroid points in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, copy, create

I would like to create rectangles that placed on given centroid points.

1. There are hundreds of points.
2. Certain rectangle shape(not a square) file is given.
3. Create rectangles that place the centroid of it on the hundreds of points each.

I've tried to copy and paste manually but I need an automated process.

Any idea?

[image: Exmaple]

Comment: please provide more details. Provide an example of the file that contains rectangles information? Meaning, how rectangles can be related to points?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very simplified version of @crmackey's script (no offense intended crmackey, it just doesn't have to be that complicated):

```py
import arcpy
w = 100
h = 50
polygons = []
sr = arcpy.Describe("points").spatialReference
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("points","SHAPE@",spatial_reference=sr) as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
         polygon = arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(row[0].centroid.X - w/2,row[0].centroid.Y + h/2),arcpy.Point(row[0].centroid.X - w/2, row[0].centroid.Y - h/2),arcpy.Point(row[0].centroid.X + w/2,row[0].centroid.Y - h/2),arcpy.Point(row[0].centroid.X + w/2,row[0].centroid.Y + h/2)]),sr)
         polygons.append(polygon)

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(polygons,r'in_memory\rectangles')
```

Comment: I realize this could have been written in less lines, but that doesn't necessarily mean "better".  What you call "complicated", I call more dynamic.  My code allows the values to be set either as constants, or by values from fields.  I would also argue that the code I posted is more portable and can easily be turned into a script tool.  And finally, the code above assumes that no attributes are needed for the output geometry.  I included them.  No offense intended here either, just explaining why I did what I did :)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, you can use constant values for your width (X) and height(Y) or the values can be defined by fields:

```py
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

def getPoly(pt, w, h):
    x, y = pt
    ll = (x - (w * 0.5), y - (h * 0.5))
    ul = (x - (w * 0.5), y + (h * 0.5))
    ur = (x + (w * 0.5), y + (h * 0.5))
    lr = (x + (w * 0.5), y - (h * 0.5))
    return arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*coords) for coords in [ll,ul,ur,lr,ll]]))

def pointsToPoly(points, output, w=500, h=500, from_field=False, w_field='', h_field=''):
    """Creates polygons from centroids by user defined width and height

    Required:
        points -- centroid points
        output -- output polygons

    Optional:
        w -- width (constant, in X direction)
        h -- height (constant, in Y direction)
        from_field -- if true, will set width and height from fields. Default is False.
        w_field -- width field.  Ignored if from_field is set to False.
        h_field -- height field.  Ignored if from_field is set to False.
    """

    # copy schema
    desc = arcpy.Describe(points)
    sr = desc.spatialReference
    path, name = os.path.split(output)
    arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(path, name, 'POLYGON', points, spatial_reference=sr)

    # create geometry
    fields = [f.name for f in desc.fields if not f.required]
    if from_field:
        w_ind, h_ind = fields.index(w_field), fields.index(h_field)
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(points, ['SHAPE@XY'] + fields) as rows:
            with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(output, ['SHAPE@'] + fields) as irows:
                for row in rows:
                    irows.insertRow((getPoly(row[0], row[w_ind+1], row[h_ind+1]),) + row[1:])

    else:
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(points, ['SHAPE@XY'] + fields) as rows:
            with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(output, ['SHAPE@'] + fields) as irows:
                for row in rows:
                    irows.insertRow((getPoly(row[0], w, h),) + row[1:])
    arcpy.AddMessage('Created: "{0}"'.format(output))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pts = r'C:\TEMP\Utility\Utilities.gdb\San_Ls'
    out = r'C:\TEMP\Utility\Utilities.gdb\polygons2'

    # test with constants
    pointsToPoly(pts, out, 750, 1000)


    # test with fields
    out2 = r'C:\TEMP\Utility\Utilities.gdb\polygons3'
    pointsToPoly(pts, out2, from_field=1, w_field='Width', h_field='Height')
    print 'done'
```

Output from fields:

[image: Output from fields]

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to write some python scripting for this. You would cycle through your point file and compute the coordinates of the 4 four corners of each rectangle and use those to construct the polygon, then write that to your output Feature Class.

Look [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001v000000) for advice and sample code on creating geometries and writing them out.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone. Really appreciated!
As a beginner in scripting and python, I tryed to find out finalized menu.

Here's the way to make rectangle....
https://www.gisnuts.com/terra/site-code-RectangularBufferTool

Also I'm trying to learn the scripting.