# Generating polygons from centroids with rotation and dimensions

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, centroids

I found this from @crmackey at [Creating rectangles on centroid points in ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134548/create-rectangles-on-centroid-points-in-arcgis)

It is exactly what I was looking for and works great, however I need to add rotation to the polygons.

How could I add this to @crmackey's python script?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Thank you for having taken the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add some math to your coordinates:

```
X = x*cos(θ) - y*sin(θ)
Y = x*sin(θ) + y*cos(θ)
```

or in this case, if the point is not (0,0):

```
X = x + xvariation*cos(θ) - yvariation*sin(θ)
Y = x + xvariation*sin(θ) + yvariation*cos(θ)
```

The code become:

```
import arcpy 
import math

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
fc = mypointfeatureclass

fields = ['SHAPE@XY']

h = 10                 #hight
w = 20                 #width
r = (10/360)*math.pi*2 #rotation (10° in this case)

# We define a small function which calculate the rectangle coordinates from point
def rotatexy(x,y,w,h,r):
    ul = arcpy.Point(x-w/2*math.cos(r)-h/2*math.sin(r),-w/2*math.sin(r)+y+h/2*math.cos(r))
    ll = arcpy.Point(x-w/2*math.cos(r)+h/2*math.sin(r),-w/2*math.sin(r)+y-h/2*math.cos(r))
    lr = arcpy.Point(x+w/2*math.cos(r)+h/2*math.sin(r),w/2*math.sin(r)+y-h/2*math.cos(r))
    ur = arcpy.Point(x+w/2*math.cos(r)-h/2*math.sin(r),w/2*math.sin(r)+y+h/2*math.cos(r))
    return arcpy.Array([ul,ll,lr,ur])


polygons = []

# For each points in feature class we create a new polygon
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
   for row in cursor:
       X = row[0][0]
       Y = row[0][1]
       print("X: {}, Y: {}".format(X,Y))
       polygon = arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([rotatexy(X,Y,w,h,r)]))
       polygons.append(polygon)

# Save the output
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(polygons,outputrectangle)
```