# Distributing object distance using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, distribution

Is there any tool in ArcGIS Pro, which could help me arrange objects to my  desired distance?

As an example, to see you what I am trying to achieve. ( in example objects are in chaotic distances)

[image]

Comment: Distances to what? Also your shapes are irregularly?

Comment: Yeah, my shapes are irregulary (but thats other problem). Distance is between those objects (for example each objecto distance to another is 1 meter)

Comment: Why not create touching polygons and buffer them by -1 m?

Comment: I cant delete them, they have inofrmation and pictures attached to them by collector

Comment: Information may be transferred using a join.

Comment: Is it  the only way ?

Comment: Probably not, but currently there could be some more specifications on your current data, your intended output, and the requirements to the process (e.g. keeping the attributes on the current features).

Comment: Well, this is a cemetary project. And those objects are graves. Because i was working outside, its pretty hard to draw correct measurments and distances by hand in collector. So i need to move them by ~1 m in distance from each othe. Also i need all the data there to keep;.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

I would start over by create points along lines at an equal interval: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/create-point-features-along-a-line.htm. I would use a distance that represents the distances between the centroids of the polygons you want. Then I would construct polygons from each of those points, considering a script like this: [Generating polygons from centroids with rotation and dimensions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271544/generating-polygons-from-centroids-with-rotation-and-dimensions).